# Return filename to datagrid - sub directories

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I have a little vb.net function that returns filenames and other data, which works great. However I need it return all files in the directory and sub directories I set it to. I need it to dig deeper into the folders not just in the exact folder I point it to.  If I set the directory "X:\Userfiles\" it will only look at that exact folder, instead of starting there and scanning all sub directories.

Any ideas guys? Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Fileinfo_To_DataTable(path.Text)
End Sub


Private Function Fileinfo_To_DataTable(ByVal directory As String) As DataTable
    Try
        'Create a new data table
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable

        'Add the following columns:
        '                          Name
        '                          Length
        '                          Last Write Time
        ''                         Creation Time
        dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn("Name"), New DataColumn("Length", GetType(Long)), New DataColumn("Last Write Time", GetType(Date)), New DataColumn("Creation Time", GetType(Date))})

        'Loop through each file in the directory
        For Each file As IO.FileInfo In New IO.DirectoryInfo(directory).GetFiles
            'Create a new row
            Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow

            'Set the data
            dr(0) = file.Name
            dr(1) = file.Length
            dr(2) = file.LastWriteTime
            dr(3) = file.CreationTime

            'Add the row to the data table
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next

        'Return the data table
        Return dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)





        'Return nothing if something fails
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Even if you have a replacement code that will serve the same function, I wont mind replacing it. Thank you

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Comment: I've tried implementing it here:

 DataGridView1.DataSource = Fileinfo_To_DataTable(path.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Still not working with subdirs

Comment: if you don't have access to certain directories, it wouldn't work